# Hover through Margin

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The HTML is as follows (I'm using React BTW) :

```css
.iss {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.heading-section {
  margin-top: 250px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.dgs-heading {
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
}

.dgs-para {
  color: white;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.iss:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="dragon-sim">
  <img class="iss" src="https://spacecraftearth.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ISS-Earth-Mediterranean-2.jpg" alt="iss-img" />
  <div class="heading-section">
    <h1 class="dgs-heading">SpaceX Dragon 2 Simulator</h1>
    <p class="dgs-para">Dock the SpaceX Dragon 2 Satellite to the International Space Station in this realtime simulator with the controls our astronauts use on their missions.</p>
    <Button variant='outlined' class="dgs-btn"><a
      href="https://iss-sim.spacex.com/">Try Now</a></Button>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is the heading section to be centered over the image. The image is at z - index = -1.

The next thing is that the image to be blurred when hovered over. But the problem is that the padding or margin is getting in the way and is blocking the hover effect.

Comment: If your z-index is -1 how do you expect it the image to be hovered over? I don't think your margin or padding is the problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly this is what you're lopoking for.  Remove `pointer-events: none;` and change the `position: absolute;` to the `.heading-section` instead of the image.  As well as add this code:

```
.dragon-sim {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here's a working example (I changed `className` to `class` just for this example to run, just change it back for react)

Edit: Add this to your CSS to get a blur even when hovering over the header.

```
.dragon-sim:hover .iss {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Example here:

```css
.iss {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}


.dragon-sim {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading-section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


.dgs-heading {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    margin: auto;
}

.dgs-para {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}


.dragon-sim:hover .iss {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="dragon-sim">
  <img class="iss"
       src="https://spacecraftearth.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ISS-Earth-Mediterranean-2.jpg"
       alt="iss-img"/>
  <div class="heading-section">
    <h1 class="dgs-heading">SpaceX Dragon 2 Simulator</h1>
    <p class="dgs-para">Dock the SpaceX Dragon 2 Satellite to the
      International Space Station in this realtime simulator with the controls
      our astronauts use on their missions.</p>
    <Button variant='outlined' class="dgs-btn"><a
      href="https://iss-sim.spacex.com/">Try Now</a></Button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This centres the heading but as soon as you hover over it the blur on the background disappears, it's not really specified in the question but I think this should not happen

Comment: That's a very easy fix.  Just add this to the CSS code:  `.dragon-sim:hover .iss {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}`  I'll update my answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

First, please indent your html code when asking for question.

try the following to center `.heading-section`

```
.heading-section {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `.heading-section` to `position: absolute`, and `pointer-events: none`, the hover will pass through to the underlying image.

View this in full page mode:

```css
.iss {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/* heading overlay: use absolute positioning */
.heading-section {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    pointer-events: none; /* passes hover to img */
}

.dgs-heading {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    margin: auto;
}

.dgs-para {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

/* override "pointer-events: none" to allow button click */
.dgs-btn {
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.iss:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="dragon-sim">
  <img class="iss"
       src="https://spacecraftearth.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ISS-Earth-Mediterranean-2.jpg"
       alt="iss-img"/>
  <div class="heading-section">
    <h1 class="dgs-heading">SpaceX Dragon 2 Simulator</h1>
    <p class="dgs-para">Dock the SpaceX Dragon 2 Satellite to the
      International Space Station in this realtime simulator with the controls
      our astronauts use on their missions.</p>
    <button class="dgs-btn" onclick="alert('click')">Try Now</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice your solution does work :), the only problem I want to mention is that with your implementation the button inside the heading-section is not clickable, I solved that in a different way in my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a wrapper which contains both the image and the header and, when that wrapper is hovered on you then blur the image.

Naturally you can centre the heading-section in the way Kevin mentioned.

So based on what I said my solution would be, same html and the css would become something like:

```
.iss {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.heading-section {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.dgs-heading {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    margin: auto;
}

.dgs-para {
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
}

.iss:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}

.dragon-sim {
    position: relative;
}

.dragon-sim:hover > .iss {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}
```

This seems to be doing what you wanted, it blurs the image but not the text and you can still interact with the text and button no problem.

Also the text is not very readable I would suggest putting some transparent background for the heading-section

Also note that I removed the `pointer-events: none;` as that is no longer necessary, plus with that you would not be able to click the button, so you definitely do not want to use that property

Comment: Also my answer solves the various issues but you may still want to add some other styles like for text-align and stuff like that, but this should already solve the main issue you asked in the question I believe

Comment: I edited my solution after John's one made me realise that actually the image does not need to have an absolute positioning  :)